# Taking away all previous values in a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am  using some data where I need to find the time difference between all previous rows i.e. in row 3 I need to know the time between row 2 and row 1 and row 2 and row 0, in row 5 i need to know the time between row 5 and row 4, row 5 and row 3.... row 5 and row 0. I then want to have a big dataframe with all these differences in (as well as the other columns).

I have made a test dataframe for this

```
data = {random': [1, 3, 9, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10],
        'timestamp': [2, 138, 157, 232, 245, 302, 323, 379]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I then tried to do

```
for i in range(0,len(df-1)):
    difference = df.timestamp.diff(periods=i+1)
    print(difference)
```

To iterate through each row and takeaway the previous row the first iteration, the second row the second iteration etc.

I am stuck on how to combine this into one large dataframe after all the iterations AND how to make sure the loop uses the original dataframe at the start of each iteration (not the dataframe from the previous iteration).

This is what is being outputted

```
0      NaN
1    136.0
2     19.0
3     75.0
4     13.0
5     57.0
6     21.0
7     56.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
0      NaN
1      NaN
2    155.0
3     94.0
4     88.0
5     70.0
6     78.0
7     77.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3    230.0
4    107.0
5    145.0
6     91.0
7    134.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4    243.0
5    164.0
6    166.0
7    147.0
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5    300.0
6    185.0
7    222.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5      NaN
6    321.0
7    241.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5      NaN
6      NaN
7    377.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   NaN
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
```

If anyone knows how to solve this that would be great :)

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of solving the problem with `Series.expanding`:

```
df['diff'] = [list(s.iat[-1] - s[-2::-1])  for s in df['timestamp'].expanding(1)]
```

---

```
   random  timestamp                               diff
0       1          2                                 []
1       3        138                              [136]
2       9        157                          [19, 155] #--> 157-138, 157-2
3       3        232                      [75, 94, 230] #--> 232-157, 232-138, 232-2
4       4        245                 [13, 88, 107, 243]
5       7        302            [57, 70, 145, 164, 300]
6       8        323        [21, 78, 91, 166, 185, 321]
7      10        379  [56, 77, 134, 147, 222, 241, 377]
```

Comment: @razzle_dazzle Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you mean but if you're asking how to collect these differences together:

```
differences = [df.timestamp.diff(periods=i+1) for i in range(0,len(df-1))]
differences = pd.concat(differences)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also may be misunderstanding, but this is the best representation I could think of from what you described:

```
>>> df2 = df.copy()
>>> for i in df2.timestamp:
        df2[i]=df2['timestamp']-i
    
>>> df2
   random  timestamp    2  138  157  232  245  302  323  379
0       1          2    0 -136 -155 -230 -243 -300 -321 -377
1       3        138  136    0  -19  -94 -107 -164 -185 -241
2       9        157  155   19    0  -75  -88 -145 -166 -222
3       3        232  230   94   75    0  -13  -70  -91 -147
4       4        245  243  107   88   13    0  -57  -78 -134
5       7        302  300  164  145   70   57    0  -21  -77
6       8        323  321  185  166   91   78   21    0  -56
7      10        379  377  241  222  147  134   77   56    0
```